# Terraform - AWS - CreateSecurityGroup - parameter GroupName is invalid. Group names may not be in the format sg-*

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to create an AWS EKS cluster using terraform and in the sequence of steps, I have a step to create a security group where I get an error to which I couldn't get a solution.

Could you guys have a look and help me understand why is this error occurring.

Using terraform version v0.13.1

Request & Response Logs:

```
2020-09-03T17:10:09.598+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: Action=CreateSecurityGroup&GroupDescription=Managed+by+Te
rraform&GroupName=sg-worker_group_mgmt_two2020090311400XXXXXXXXXXXX&Version=2016-11-15&VpcId=vpc-XXXXXXXX
2020-09-03T17:10:09.598+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: 2020/09/03 17:10:10 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response 
ec2/CreateSecurityGroup Details:
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: Connection: close
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2020 11:40:09 GMT
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: Server: AmazonEC2
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: 
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: 
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: 2020/09/03 17:10:10 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1
.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: <Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Cod
e><Message>Value (sg-worker_group_mgmt_two2020090311400XXXXXXXXXXXX) for parameter GroupName is invalid. Group names may not be in the
 format sg-*.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>5XXXX-0XXX-4c55-aXXa-b34f3XXXXX</RequestID></Response>
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5: 2020/09/03 17:10:10 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate 
Response ec2/CreateSecurityGroup failed, attempt 0/25, error InvalidParameterValue: Value (sg-worker_group_mgmt_two2020090311400XXXXXXXXXXXX) for parameter GroupName is invalid. Group names may not be in the format sg-*.
2020-09-03T17:10:10.360+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.4.0_x5:   status code: 400, request id: 5XXXX-0XXX-4c55-aXXa-b34f3XXXXX
2020/09/03 17:10:10 [DEBUG] aws_security_group.worker_group_mgmt_two: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error pointer rather than returning it: Error creating Security Group: InvalidParameterValue: Value (sg-worker_group_mgmt_two2020090311400XXXXXXXXXXXX) for parameter GroupName is invalid. Group names may not be in the format sg-*.
        status code: 400, request id: 5XXXX-0XXX-4c55-aXXa-b34f3XXXXX
```

Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg-worker_group_mgmt_one" {
  name_prefix = "sg-worker_group_mgmt_one"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc-dev-cluster.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"

    cidr_blocks = [
      "xxx.xx.0.0/16",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg-worker_group_mgmt_two" {
  name_prefix = "sg-worker_group_mgmt_two"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc-dev-cluster.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"

    cidr_blocks = [
      "xxx.xx.0.0/16",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg-all_worker_mgmt" {
  name_prefix = "sg-all_worker_management"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc-dev-cluster.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"

    cidr_blocks = [
      "xxx.xx.xx.0/17",
      "xxx.xx.0.0/16",
    ]
  }
}


resource "aws_security_group" "sg-eks_cluster" {
  name        = "${var.cluster_sg_name}"
  description = "Cluster communication with worker nodes"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc-dev-cluster.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.cluster_sg_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg-cluster_inbound" {
  description              = "Allow worker nodes to communicate with the cluster API Server"
  from_port                = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_cluster.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_nodes.id}"
  to_port                  = 443
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sg-cluster_outbound" {
  description              = "Allow cluster API Server to communicate with the worker nodes"
  from_port                = 1024
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_cluster.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_nodes.id}"
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "egress"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg-eks_nodes" {
  name        = "${var.nodes_sg_name}"
  description = "Security group for all nodes in the cluster"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc-dev-cluster.id}"

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.nodes_sg_name}"
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.eks_cluster_name}" = "owned"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "nodes" {
  description              = "Allow nodes to communicate with each other"
  from_port                = 0
  protocol                 = "-1"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_nodes.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_nodes.id}"
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "nodes_inbound" {
  description              = "Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane"
  from_port                = 1025
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_nodes.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sg-eks_cluster.id}"
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include your Terraform code?

Comment: Added terraform code to the question.

Comment: It's as it says. You can't prefix the security group name with `sg-` because that's how the security group identifiers are prefixed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSecurityGroup.html shows the limitations. Ideally Terraform would have caught that at the plan stage but seems to be missing that validation and is only checking the length of the name.

Comment: Thanks its clear and fixed. You can add it as answer. I can upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AWS documentation for CreateSecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSecurityGroup.html) mentions the following restrictions on the `name`:

> Constraints: Up to 255 characters in length. Cannot start with sg-.

Normally the AWS provider would have a validation for this so it would show up from either the `plan` or `validate` commands. Unfortunately it currently only has a validation checking the length.

To fix your error you'll need to change the name of your security group to remove the `sg-` prefix.

I've raised https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/15011 to fix this so in future it can be detected before running the `apply`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it.